# Common Lisp Unbound Variable

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

Is it possible to use an uninitialized variable as a function argument? For an assignment, I have to use the CLOS to write a semantic network system, and my professor included a test function to test our output, and one of them specifies:

`(print (def-concept Human))`,

which implies passing the argument Human to the function def-concept. When running this test function, I cannot get away from the error (in Allegro CL):

`Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable`HUMAN'.`

As this is the first function in the test, there is no initializing of any variables before this. Is there any way to get around passing an uninitialized variable as an argument of a function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be useful to ask your professor for help.

Comment: unfortunately, it honestly would/has not.

Comment: You can pass in a symbol, which may not have any binding whatsoever, and attempt to retrieve its bindings inside your function. That said, could you not initialise first?

Comment: Is it even possible to pass in a symbol? I cannot even get into the function because the error stops me as soon as it sees that the argument is unbound.

Comment: Are you sure `def-concept` is a function? Maybe it's a macro? What's the answer of `(describe 'def-concept)`?

Comment: Ah, I see. It is in fact a macro (although I'm not sure what difference it makes). The output of `describe 'def-concept` is: DEF-CONCEPT is a TENURED SYMBOL.
  It is unbound.
  It is INTERNAL in the COMMON-GRAPHICS-USER package.
  Its function binding is #<Interpreted Function DEF-CONCEPT>
    which function takes arguments (CLASSNAME)

Comment: you pass in a symbol by quoing, like this: `(print (def-concept 'Human))`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to use an unitialized value as a function argument in a regular Common Lisp function call. Common Lisp uses eager evaluation: argument expressions are reduced to their values before the function call takes place.

I suspect maybe you don't exactly understand the structure of the homework assignment.

If `def-concept` is a function which expects a value, and `human` is not defined, you simply cannot test that function.

Perhaps you are expected to define the variable `human` and then load the file containing `(print (def-concept human))`.

Just because there is nothing prior to that form in the same file doesn't mean that no prior evaluation is possible. Other files can be loaded before that file, or forms evaluated in the listener.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is perfectly possible that I don't understand the structure of the assignment, and I am currently awaiting a response from my instructor regarding this. It seems it could be an error in the test function because I agree that it is not possible to use an uninitialized value as an argument. The rest of the test commands include a quote before the arguments (like 'Human), so perhaps this one was meant for that too. Otherwise, I'm certain that we shouldn't be loading anything prior to evaluating the test cases.

Comment: Could be a typo then. Everyone in the class will be running into the same thing; have you talked to others. :)

Comment: Hmm well ok, so it was supposed to be a macro, so changing the definition of `def-concept` to `defmacro` instead of `defun` worked. Although now I'm getting incorrect output..